# How to add text outside a ggplot2 plot using npc coordinates in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am using a function in R to subset data and plot each of those subsets, and mapping (purrr::map) the function over a list of the subsets. I would like to be able to label the plots with a letter in the top left, in a position that remains constant despite the varying ranges of the axes. In other words, I want to use a normalized coordinate system, but I want to use negative values.

I have tried using ggpp::geom_text_npc(), which functions perfectly within the plot, but any values outside of the 0 to 1 range seem to just "round" to values inside the plot. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(ggpp)

datumz<-data.frame(ex = c(1:5, 11:15),
                   why = c(rep(1:5,2)),
                   kat = c(rep("a", 5),rep("b", 5)))
                   
selex<-list(c("a", "A"),
            c("b", "B"))
                  
grafz<-function(a){

  part<-datumz %>% 
    filter(kat==a[1])

  ggplot(part)+
    geom_point(mapping=aes(ex, why))+

    coord_cartesian(clip='off')+
    ggpp::geom_text_npc(size=8,aes(npcx=-.2, npcy=1.2, label=a[2]))
  
}

purrr::map(selex,grafz)
```

Places the text consistently across the two plots (which is good), but I can't find npcx or npcy values that would print outside of the plot box.

Comment: One possible option would be to use `annotation_custom`. However, you have to be aware that `npc` refers to the width and height of the plot area and you would still have to add some margin to make room for your labels. This said have you considered adding your labels via e.g. `labs(tag = ...)`?

Comment: Thanks Stefan. For some reason I was so focused on making a label by adding text that it didn't occur to me to explore labeling options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `patchwork` package has some good functionality for figure tags. See below for how to add to 1) a set of combined figures with automatic sequencing, 2) a single figure with a custom tag, or 3) as a drop-in replacement for your `ggpp::geom_text_npc` line.

```
library(patchwork)
ggplot(subset(datumz, kat == "a"))+
  geom_point(mapping=aes(ex, why))+
  coord_cartesian(clip='off') +
ggplot(subset(datumz, kat == "b"))+
  geom_point(mapping=aes(ex, why))+
  coord_cartesian(clip='off') +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "A")
```

[image]

Or if you want to make a single panel at a time:

```
ggplot(subset(datumz, kat == "b"))+
  geom_point(mapping=aes(ex, why))+
  coord_cartesian(clip='off') +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = list("B"))
```

[image]

So a drop-in replacement for your `ggpp::geom_text_npc` line could be:

```
plot_annotation(tag_levels = list(a[2]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and for introducing me to patchwork. labs(tag=...)  worked well in this specific circumstance, but the flexibility to deal with multiple figures in different scenarios is extremely helpful.